# raise KeyError(key) from err

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am going to itterate over the taitanic dataset. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

!wget "https://calmcode.io/datasets/titanic.csv"
dt = pd.read_csv("./titanic.csv", index_col=["PassengerId"])

def impute_cabin_values(X):
    for i in range(len(X)):
        print(X["Pclass"][i])

impute_cabin_values(dt)
```

And then i face with the following error:

```
 raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

why should index `0` in the `print(X["Pclass"][i])` not working ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get `ValueError: Index ` invalid` while reading ` ./titanic.csv'. There is no `PassengerId` column. Also there is `pclass` column, not `Pclass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you set your dataframe index as `PassengerId` on this part.

```
dt = pd.read_csv("./titanic.csv", index_col=["PassengerId"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing by nonexistent column `PassengerId` and trying to fetch nonexistent column `Pclass` instead of `pclass`.
Assuming this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#!wget "https://calmcode.io/datasets/titanic.csv"
dt = pd.read_csv("./titanic.csv") #, index_col=["PassengerId"])

def impute_cabin_values(X):
    for i in range(len(X)):
        print(X["pclass"][i])

impute_cabin_values(dt)
```

Results:

```
1
3
1
3
1
3
3
2
...
```